# How to remove words from string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove characters from string if characters number `>` than `10` and insert three dots `...`

```
I need remove characters
I need remov...//like this text
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, JavaScript does just fine. What have you tried?

Comment: RegExp solution : http://jsfiddle.net/ss9e4tev/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I would upvote that just for the Breaking Bad reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roy mentioned, you don't need jQuery to do this. Plain JavaScript works just fine.

Try:

```
if (str.length > 10)
    str = str.substring(0, 10) + '...'
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9q6h1Lmk/).

Another way is to use the ternary operator. It's shorter but not as readable if you aren't used to the ternary syntax:

```
str = (str.length > 10) ? str.substring(0, 10) + '...' : str;
```

This is equivalent to the `if` statement above.